# Ignore a node while backup is active (GLB)

Tags: load-balancing, centos6, galera, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'm building a HA cluster with CentOS 6

I have n number of database nodes (using percona xtradb cluster), and when backup process starts, I change the "wsrep_desync" to ON, this way locks caused by the backup tool doesn't affect to the other nodes. This is OK, but galera load balancer is still sending queries to that server.

There is any way to change galera load balancer configuration on application servers, to ignore the node while wsrep_desync is ON?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the backup software is being used for backups?

Comment: Percona Xtrabackup